# Xamarin - change keyboard type for webview (Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I change android keyboard type to Numeric for WebView? Or can I change android keyboard type for whole project?

Comment: You need to change the type of your <input> to make it use Numeric. For example, `<input type="number />`

Comment: I can not change the input type in target web pages, so I need to set the keyboard "numeric" for whole project (or for webview control).